# Tracking which item is checked in a dropdownlist

Tags: vb.net

for an assignment in my class I had to make a super simple point of sale system and one of the features required was tracking how many of each item is sold. I know I can do it with If statements such as

```
If DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    ddl1Tracker += 1
ElseIf DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    ddl2Tracker +=1
Etc...
End IF
```

but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it so I don't need to make a variable to track each individual item?

Thanks

Comment: Each CheckedListBox item can only be checked or unchecked, so the count is only ever going to be 1 or 0.  If they uncheck something, your "counters" are going to be off.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry! I accidentally wrote checkboxlist instead of dropdownlist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace a bunch of `ddlNTracker` variables with an array:

```
Dim ddlTrackers(ddlCount-1) as Integer
```

And then replace the whole `If` section with a single function call:

```
ddlTrackers(DropDownList.SelectedIndex) += 1
```